# WordPress Algolia - indexing ACF repeater fields as custom attributes

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I am trying to index ACF fields as custom attributes. As per Algolia documentation (https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/advanced-custom-fields.html) I managed to index simple ACF fields. I managed to index also repeater field but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. Is there anyone that managed to resolve this issue and is able to not only index the ACF repeater fields but later pull them on Instantsearch template when searching on WordPress site?

```
add_filter( 'algolia_post_shared_attributes', 'my_event_attributes', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'algolia_searchable_post_shared_attributes', 'my_event_attributes', 10, 2 );


function my_event_attributes( array $attributes, WP_Post $post ) {

if ( 'events' !== $post->post_type ) {

    return $attributes;
}


$attributes['description'] = get_field( 'event_description', $post->ID );
$attributes['time'] = get_field( 'event_time', $post->ID );
$attributes['date'] = get_field( 'event_date', $post->ID );
$repeater = get_field( 'event_schedules', $post->ID );

$x = 0;


foreach ($repeater as $item) {
    unset($item['schedule_info']);


    $schedules = array ('location'=>$item['location'],'location_new'=>$item['location_new'],'event_date'=>$item['event_date'],'start_time'=>$item['start_time'],'end_time'=>$item['end_time'], 'all_day'=>$item['all_day'], 'cancel'=>$item['cancel'], 'is_location_change'=>$item['is_location_change']);
    $attributes['event_schedules'][$x] = $schedules;
    $x = $x + 1;
}


return $attributes;
}
```

---

Algolia Dashboard

[image: [1]]

Comment: Also discussed here https://discourse.algolia.com/t/wordpress-acf-repeater-field-into-index/1837/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is fundamental difference here in the WordPress backend and the way Algolia indexes CPT. You can index all the CPT's in Plugin settings -> Autocomplete and you can index the general main list under Plugin settings -> Search Page. If you are creating your own search template you can index only specific CPT that you are currently working with, but if you are working on the default search instantsearch template then you need to index the general index.